# How can I not show insertions in the Integrative Genome Viewer (IGV)?

Tags: sequence-alignment, visualization, igv

I am using IGV 2.5.2 and would not like to see the insertions  in my aligned reads. How can I do that? I have managed to remove mismatched bases because there is an option to do so when I right-click on the window ("Show mismatched bases"). Now I would like to do the same with these purple insertions.

[image: IGV screenshot]

#### 3rd January 2020 update

[image: IGV preferences]

Thanks to a member's response, I found some parameter in the preferences that might be helpful to hide the indels. However, I have tried different numbers from 0 to 1000 and the indels are still shown. What numbers should I put to the parameters "Show indel threshold (bases)" and should I click the box or not?

Comment: Check the box and try `1` as the threshold.

Answer (score 3):

Preferences `->` Alignments `->` Hide indels < 'x' bases.

---

Credit to [Pierre Lindenbaum](https://www.biostars.org/p/339007/)